# subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ whose shifts have finite intersection property in density

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics

I am interested in proving the statement:

> Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $r\in\mathbb{N}$ and for every $k_{1}$, $k_{2}$, $\ldots$, $k_{r}\in\mathbb{N}$, the set $\big(S-k_{1}\big) \cap \big(S-k_{2}\big) \cap \ldots \cap \big(S-k_{r}\big)$ has positive density in $\mathbb{N}$. Then the set $S$ must have density $1$. The density I have in mind is not natural density but Banach density.

To prove the statement, imagine that such a set $S$ does not have full density.

If $S = \bigcup_{i=0}^{j} a\mathbb{N}+i$ is the union of $j < a$ arithmetic progressions, we can see that for $r =a$ and taking $k_{1} = 0, k_{2} = 1, \ldots, k_{a} = a$, the intersection is empty — a contradiction. Similarly, we would also reach a contradiction for a set $S$ of the form $\bigcup_{s=1}^{n}\Big(\bigcup_{i=0}^{j_{s}} a_{s}\mathbb{N}+i \Big)$, where all $a_{s}$ are distinct, $j_{s} < a_{s}$ for each $1 \leq s \leq n$. So, this would also be true if the set $S$ were contained in $\bigcup_{s=1}^{n}\Big(\bigcup_{i=0}^{j_{s}} a_{s}\mathbb{N}+i \Big)$ of the above form.

However, for a general $S$, I am neither sure of the statement nor its proof. I would appreciate any help or feedback.

Comment: Which type of density?

Comment: For natural density it is false. Consider any set whose prefixes are Følner in the sense that the set is eventually built from longer and longer intervals. Then your intersections don't change density.

Comment: What about Banach density? I will also include that in the question as you reminded me.

Comment: For Banach density 1, you can just observe that there are arbitrarily long intervals there, taking the $k_i$ to form an interval.